# Капча в приложении, не использующем сессии

Tags: php, symfony, captcha

В приложении требуется использовать капчу. Генерация и проверка капчи должна быть реализована локально, без использования внешних сервисов проверки. Практически все реализации капчи используют сессию. Фраза сохраняется в сессии пользователя и при проверке сравнивается пришедшая фраза с фразой из сессии.

А как быть, если приложение не использует сессии? Пока придумал только:

- Генерировать случайный ключ
- Генерировать капчу и сохранять в фразу в кэше с этим ключом
- Передавать пользователю ключ + картинку
- При отправке формы извлекать фразу из кэша по ключу и сравнивать с присланной

Меня смущает безопасность такого решения. Фактически при каждом обновлении картинки/страницы в кэш добавляется новая запись. Можно, разумеется, задать маленькое время жизни для таких записей, но менее 10 минут не задашь (мало ли как будет тупить пользователь над формой). Не получится ли из такого решения потенциальная бомба, когда сайту могут забить весь кэш одними только обновлениями страницы?

Второй вариант, который приходит в голову, - это:

- формировать ключ на стороне клиента
- сохранять ключ в локальном хранилище браузера
- использовать этот ключ при запросе капчи
- сохранять фразу в кэш с полученным от клиента ключом
- при повторном запросе капчи обновлять фразу в кэше с этим ключом

таким образом сократить кол-во записей капчи в кэше. Но тут меня беспокоит вопрос безопасности (может я параноик?) Не сможет ли человек нагенерить капчей и передать оптом спам боту, который за время жизни записей в кэше понаделает регистраций? )))

Буду рад, если поделитесь примерами реализации капчи без использования сессий? Проект на symfony, но это особой роли не играет, главное алгоритм.

Comment: А как у вас без сессий происходит  И все таки интересно почему без сессий ?

Comment: @zalex аутентификация с jwt-токеном

Comment: Решили ли вы как то свою задачу ? 
Я просто тут подумал что не используя сессии вы попросту заново должны придумать механизм, который заменит сессии. 
Вот и возник интерес, что именно побудило вас не использовать сессии, есть этому какая то резонная причина ?

Comment: @zalex в принципе ничего нового. stateless - приложение. клииенту отдается jwt-токен, который клиент отправляет в заголовке при каждом запросе. в токене содержится нужная для авторизации информация. Если не использовать сессии, то снимается проблема работы через апи с разных приложений и можно использовать кластеры на бэкенде. Но вот возникла потребность сделать механизм "восстановить пароль", когда пользователь 100% не авторизован и никакого токена у него нет. Заказчик хочет капчу, чтобы уменьшить кол-во запросов на восстановление от роботов

Comment: Все равно не вижу проблему. Закрываете восстановление пароля другим файрволом, хранение сессии переносите в базу данных, редис, куда угодно (из коробки работает) и jwt у вас работает без сессий, восстановление с сессиями, и бэкенд если у вас за балансировщиком тоже без проблем видит сессии для капчи.